# Using one synchronized (this) instead of two?

Tags: java, multithreading

Does this:

```
synchronized (this)
{
  fork[i] = false;
  notifyAll();
}
synchronized (this)
{
  fork[j] = false;
  notifyAll();
}
System.out.println("Phil" + id + "released the forks");
```

works the same as this?

```
synchronized (this)
{
  fork[j] = fork[i] = false;
  notifyAll();
}

System.out.println("Phil" + id + "released the forks");
```

I want to know if there is a problem about making only one synchronized, thanks

Comment: Almost certainly no - for starters, you `notifyAll()` a different number of times. But it's not clear exactly what the difference might be, because you've not shown if `fork` is a member of `this`, for example.

Comment: Oh, okay then, I'll stick with the first code, thanks @Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case fork[i] and fork[j] may not take the false value at "the same time".

In the second case fork[i] and fork[j] will take both false in the same critical section.

If problems may occurs depends on what your intentions are.